# mod_rewrite subdirectory is triggering errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying out mod_rewrite on a local playground using MAMP (I know), the rule I'm using seems to be fine according to answers here on stackoverflow, but I keep getting a 404 page, even tried looking at the apache server log, and it seems to be missing the file extension even  though the rewrite rule includes it.

Here is my rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/$ public/test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Apache log entry:

```
[Sat Mar 02 00:24:02 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/public/test
```

I have verified it works by placing the same htaccess file inside the sub directory, instead of the root, oddly enough, that works.

The issue seems to be related to the fact .php is missing (based on the apache log).

Comment: And what's the requested URL that triggered this result?

Comment: http://playgnd.com/site/public/test/6/

Comment: where is the .htaccess file?

Comment: located under site/.htaccess - test.php is located in site/public/test.php

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide ?

Comment: If you change the 'L' to an 'R' in `[NC,L]` you can see what your rewriterule is doing. ;) Might come in handy

Comment: I did, now the page is loading, but I see some missing resources (css mainly).